# DLL load failed while `import dolphindb`

Tags: python, database, dll, dolphindb

I'm trying [DolphinDB python API](https://github.com/dolphindb/python3_api_experimental) to subscribe a stream table from our DolphinDB cluster. But as I run `import dolphindb` it reports

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

As I read the readme for a second time, I found that only Anaconda python is supported, because of some issue of DLL loading.

But I cannot use Anaconda for some reason, so is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The c++ version python api is based on DolphinDB's c++ api. On windows platform, c++ api is compiled by mingw so that the runtime requires mingw's core dll. The non-Anaconda doesn't come with mingw runtime and hence failed to import the DophinDB python api.

The new version of python api has included mingw's required libraries. Please check it out.